# Javascript assign table to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My goal is to create a button using javascript, that creates a table, that is the same as one I already have. Here I have a table with id="create_table_test", and a button with onsumbit function createTable().

The problem is whenever the button is executed, instead of a table I get [object HTMLTableElement] .Also tried to do it without the function getElemntById, but the result was the same.  With some testing I found that this script doesn't like input types.I tried to do it with the same table, but without the input field types set and it worked out.Maybe thats the cause ?

The next thing that maybe have to be kept in mind is that I need to store the filled tables into php variables, then insert them into table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>      
    <script>
    var table = document.getElementById("create_table_test");

            function createTable() {
        document.getElementById("create_table").innerHTML += table;
            }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="create_table">
    <table id="create_table_test" class="repeat_table">
            <tr class="tr_test" style="border-bottom:3px solid #0066FF; font-weight:bold">
                <td id="Question">
                Въпрос
                </td>
                <td>
                A
                </td>
                <td>
                B
                </td>
                <td>
                C
                </td>
                <td>
                D
                </td>
                <td>
                True answer
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
<form name="test" action="send.php" onsubmit="" method="post">

<tr>
<td>
<textarea id="question" name="question" style="width:300px; height:120px;"></textarea></td>
<td>    
<textarea id="answer1" name="answer1" style="width:80px; height:120px"></textarea></td>
<td>
<textarea id="answer2" name="answer2" style="width:80px; height:120px"></textarea></td>
<td>
<textarea id="answer3" name="answer3" style="width:80px; height:120px"></textarea></td>
<td>
<textarea id="answer4" name="answer4" style="width:80px; height:120px"></textarea></td>
<td>
<input id="true_answer" type="radio" name="true_answer" value="A">A<br>
<input id="true_answer" type="radio" name="true_answer" value="B">B<br>
<input id="true_answer" type="radio" name="true_answer" value="C">C<br>
<input id="true_answer" type="radio" name="true_answer" value="D">D<br>
</td>
<td>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="" class="btn"/>
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

 <input type="button" onclick="createTable()" value="CreateTable"/>



        </span>
</body>
```

Comment: you added jquery as tag, why are you not using it?

Answer (score 1):

try this one...

```
function createTable() {
            var table = document.getElementById("create_table_test").outerHTML;
        document.getElementById("create_table").innerHTML += table;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want:

```
document.getElementById("create_table").innerHTML += table.outerHTML;
```

But beware of duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this code from:

```
var table = document.getElementById("create_table_test");

        function createTable() {
    document.getElementById("create_table").innerHTML += table;
        }
```

to:

```
var table = document.getElementById("create_table_test");

        function createTable() {
    document.getElementById("create_table").innerHTML = table.outerHTML;
        }
```

This will create the same table with the same `ids`. You might wanna re-think your logic.

Comment: Using innerHTML property of table won't copy all the table but its content

Comment: If he's doing `getElementById()`, that means that he has the table and he needs to only copy the content.

Comment: But you code won't give valid HTML output, TR will be direct child of a SPAN and indeed would be parsed as text nodes in chrome, at least

Comment: Oh right. Didn't realize he was trying to post both under the same `<span>` and not a separate location.